# Django : ManyToMany relation error ( object has no attribute)

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

I am trying to define some ManyToMany relations in Django, but I have an error when I try to create related objects.

My models.py :

```
class PerfumeBrand(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Marque de parfum"
        verbose_name_plural = "Marques de parfum"

    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.person.first_name + ' ' +  self.person.last_name.upper() + ': ' + self.name


class Person(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Personne"
        verbose_name_plural = "Personnes"

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, )
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    # Here is the ManyToMany relation
    perfume_brands = models.ManyToManyField(PerfumeBrand)
```

The problem is that when I try to save a PerfumeBrand object in my database, I get this error :

> AttributeError at /admin/visualize/perfumebrand/add/
>
> 'PerfumeBrand' object has no attribute 'person'

I tried to save both in code and admin panel, the same error occurs.

As this is the first time I need a ManyToMany relation in a Django project, I am a bit confused, and I didn't find any solution to my problem.

Have you any idea ?

Comment: Indeed, PerfumeBrand doesn't have an attribute `person`. So why are you using `self.person` in the `__unicode__` method?

Answer (score 1):

The class `PerfumeBrand` never defines the variable `person`, only `name`.

Answer (score 1):

On the `PerfumeBrand` object, you have declared this

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.person.first_name + ' ' + self.person.last_name.upper() + ': ' + self.name
```

But `person` is not an attribute of `PerfumeBrand`. That function should be under the `Person` class (with some changes before) and you should use something like the following in the `PerfumeBrand` class:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Comment: How god, I flipped my relation and totally forget to delete the name attributed in the str.

Thanks so much !